# Python 2.7 Histogram from wod-frequency dictionary

Tags: python, histogram, frequency

I've build a dictionary with word frequencies from a huge text, out of which I want to produce a histogram. Notably, the dictionary has a size of 40000 and there are also keys with a corresponding value of 0.
   From my understanding and experience, plotting a histogram with as many bins as my dictionary keys takes much time and produces an almost unreadable chart so I searched around for optimal-bin algorithms such as Freedman-Diaconis, etc but I still can't find a way to produce an accurate and readable histogram.
   Again, from what I can understand, since my samples are that many, a proper approach would be to categorize similar frequencies in each bin (e.g words that appear 200-500 times represented by one bar?) but not "too much" so the histogram doesn't deviate from my results. I would prefer not to use fixed bin numbers and widths as my data is likely to change in the future.
   I've tried mathplotlib, pylab and pandas for the histogram plotting, and I experimented with some of their funtions' arguments as well but to no avail.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you are using Jupyter to play with your data and visualize it (which I highly recommend), you can easily make some (or all) plot parameters interactive via sliders with ipywidgets. This will help you play with the params in a way that makes finding the optimal values easier. Check this out: http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html